# Get Index value in R from boxplot

Tags: r, indexing, boxplot

I have a dataset with 170 variables and the first one is Customer ID which I converted as index of the data frame:

```
input2 <- data.frame(input2[,-1], row.names = input2[,1])
```

I want to create a data frame where I have the Customer ID that are considered outliers.

I already found the outliers:

```
 outliers <- boxplot(input2)$out
```

And found that to get the index values i can use

```
which(input2 %in% outliers)
```

but it gives as output:

```
integer(0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify do you want to know why it returns `integer(0)` or do you want to know how to filter your dataset to only the outliers or remove those outliers? Or do you want to know both?

Comment: I want to get the Index value (CustomerID) that are considered outliers by the method of boxplot

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to use a vectorised function on the index, which isn't how r functions generally work. If you want to pull an index using `which()` you need to have a column in your dataframe that contains your Customer IDs